# Implementing iterator design pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, iterator, iterable

I have a class Example witch private field `Hashmap<Integer, CustomObject>`. My goal is to access all instances of `CustomObject` in this class using the `Iterable` interface. First, I declare Example to implement `Iterable<CustomObject>`. Then I call `iterator()` method. However, I don't know if I should specify `hasNext()` etc, what to put in main code? Here is what I have so far:

```
public class Example implements Iterable<Songs>{
  private HashMap <Integer, CustomObject>;

  @Override
  public Iterator<CustomObject> iterator() {
    for (CustomObject customObject: this){
      System.out.println(customObject);
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Example.iterator();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `HashMap` has a method [`Map::values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--) that returns a collection of the values as a [`Collection<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) which actually **is-an** `Iterable<T>` (hence can return an `Iterator<T>`).

```
Map<Integer, CustomObject> map = new HashMap<>();
Iterator<CustomObject> iterator = map.values().iterator();
```

Moreover, your code has several errors:

- `private HashMap <Integer, CustomObject>;` misses the field name and possibly an initiation.
- Implementing `Iterable<Songs>` you have to override `public Iterator<CustomObject> iterator()`. I assume you mean `class Example implements Iterable<CustomObject>`.
- `Iterable::iterator` is not a static method, so you cannot call `Example.iterator();`.

A complete example assuming the `Example` is an iterable delegate of the `HashMap map` like in your class (you have forgotten to name it, otherwise it would not compile, and initialize it), then you can do this:

```
public class Example implements Iterable<CustomObject> {

    private Map<Integer, CustomObject> delegate = ...; // initialize + data

    @Override
    public Iterator<CustomObject> iterator() {
        return this.delegate.values().iterator();
    }
}
```

And use like at any of these snippets:

- As long as `Example` **is-an** `Iterable`, then it can be used with enhanced loops:

  ```
  for (CustomObject customObject: new Example()) {   // Iterable with enhanced loop
      System.out.println(customObject);
  }
  ```
- Through an actual `Iterator`:

  ```
  Iterator<CustomObject> iterator = new Example().iterator();
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println(iterator.next());
  }
  ```
- Through `Stream` as long every `Iterable` returns its `Spliterator`:

  ```
  StreamSupport.stream(new Example().spliterator(), false)
               .forEach(System.out::println);
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm required to apply the Iterator design pattern. Does this satistfy that requirement? Would I add the above piece of code in my main method? Thank you

Comment: Is it a school homework? My snippets show the *usage* of the existing implementation of the `Iterator` pattern through the JDK. If you need to *implement* one, I'd start here: https://www.journaldev.com/1716/iterator-design-pattern-java. Saying "required **to apply** the Iterator" is a bit vague to me and I'd ask a teacher for the details if I were you. So... my answer is not wrong for the usage but it depends on the context and the actual requirements. In any cases, you have your resources now.